# Is there a way to read or convert object received by request with fs.readFile

Tags: node.js, reactjs, object, hash, request

I need send an uploaded file in front-end to my back-end application to get your hash. I know one way to get a hash file is reading your buffer array (i'm sending an object instead your buffer array).

**front-end code:**

```
const [document, setDocument] = useState('');

async function onFileUpload(e) { 
// Create an object of formData 
const formData = new FormData(); 

formData.append( 
  "myFile", 
  document,
); 

// Request made to the backend api 
// Send formData object 
try {
  const response = await api.post('/uploadFile', formData); 

  console.log('response' + response);
} catch (err) {
  console.log('err' + err);
  // alert(`error`);
}
```

};

```
<input 
  placeholder="Informe um arquivo"
  type="file"
  name="file"
  onChange={e => setDocument(e.target.files[0])}
 />

 <button type="submit" onClick={onFileUpload}>Upload</button>
```

**back-end code:**

```
import cryptoJs from 'crypto-js';
import fs from 'fs';

module.exports = {
  create(request, response) {

    console.log('dm:' + request.body)

    fs.readFile(request.body, "utf8", function(err,data){
      if(err) {
        console.error("Could not open file: %s", err);
        return response.json(err);
      }else{
        var finalHash = cryptoJs.SHA256(data);
        //upToIPFS(data);
        console.log('hash: ' + finalHash)
        return response.json({ finalHash });
    }})
  }
}
```

When the file is sent to back-end, i get this error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received an instance of Object
```

I know that the request received is an object. Is there a way to convert or read the object request? or should i need change front-end code to send proper request?

If a try `request.body.document` instead just `request.body` then i get `undefined` variable.

I'm using react.js and express. node version: v12.16.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that request.body is a request object while for fs.readFile requires a file buffer or file path to data

```
fs.readFile(request.body, "utf8", function(err,data){
```

[image]

as you could see in the fs.readFile documentation.

You can use npm packages like express-fileupload

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

eg 
in ur index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const app = express();

// default options
app.use(fileUpload());


import cryptoJs from 'crypto-js';
import fs from 'fs';

module.exports = {
  create(request, response) {

    console.log('dm:' + request.body)

    fs.readFile(request.files.myFile.data, "utf8", function(err,data){
      if(err) {
        console.error("Could not open file: %s", err);
        return response.json(err);
      }else{
        var finalHash = cryptoJs.SHA256(data);
        //upToIPFS(data);
        console.log('hash: ' + finalHash)
        return response.json({ finalHash });
    }})
  }
}
```

Comment: didn't sucessed. According https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload, i named `<input name='file, type='file' />` in front-end and did the adjustment in back-end, passing `app.use(fileUpload());`. In the request, `when request.files.file` i get undefined and when only `request.files` i get the object. idk what i'm missing here *.*

Comment: Can u paste output for console.log(request.files)

Comment: `print request:[object Object]`

Comment: when `console.log(request.files.file)`: `print request:undefined`

Comment: can you try console.log(request.files. myFile) ??

Comment: with print .myFile got [object Object]

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you try the updated answer?

Comment: with .data worked! i get the document content. it will be perfect if i could get the file itself. idk why passing .file (the name of <input>) dont work.

Comment: you can try req.files. myFile.tempFilePath... hopefully, this works